# Composition of a function and its inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

Prove that $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is an bijection if and only if $g:Y\rightarrow X$ such that $g\circ f=id_X$ and $f\circ g=id_Y$

$id_X$ is defined to be an identity mapping such that $id_X:X\rightarrow X$ and $id_X(x)=x$, with all x belongs to X

I know that if $fg=id_Y$ then it is equivalent to $f\circ(y)=id_Y(y)$ and this is also equivalent to $f(g(y))=y$

While it is hard for me to see that $f(g(y))=y$ is obviously true, it helps to think of a composition of a function and its inverse, for example $\sin(\arcsin(y))=y$. However, I don't know how to prove this latter equality.

Comment: Did you mean to say that $f$ is a bijection rather than "an injection"? I have no idea what you mean by "it is hard for me to see that $f(g(y)) = y$ is obviously true".  If you're assuming that $f$ is (bijective?) and trying to prove that $f \circ g = \operatorname{id}_X$, then your only makes sense if you're talking about a specific function $g$ (whose definition should connect to $f$ in some way).

Comment: As for proving $\sin(\arcsin(y)) = y$, I would say the answer is ultimately "by definition".  For a specific proof, you'd need to give us a definition of $\arcsin$ to start with.

Comment: Let $X$ be a singleton: $X=\{x\}$. Now observe that $f:\{x\}\to Y$ is injective but for **every** $g:Y\to\{x\}$ the composition $f\circ g$ is a constant function, so that it cannot coincide $\mathsf{id}_Y$ if $Y$ has more than one element.

Comment: I have already fixed the typo. It should be bijection.

Answer (score 1):

I think the obstacle is the way you were thinking. It makes you confusing. So to prove $A \Leftrightarrow B$. You first revise If $A$ then $B$ and second If $B$ then $A$. So for necessary part $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is an injection, you always can construct such a function $g=f^{-1}$ for $y \in f(X)$, just maps every images of $X$ by $f$ back from $Y$ to $X$. For sufficient part, you have $f,g$ as above $g\circ f=id_X$ and $f\circ g=id_Y$. Now you have to revise that the function $f$ is a injection, that is for every $y$ in the image of $X$ by $f$, there only one $x$ such that $f(x)=y$. You can see, that's indeed right by contradiction if we supposed that there are two $x_1,x_2$ such $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=y$. Then there is no such $g$.

Comment: you mean bijection instead of injection?

Comment: @JamesWarthington No, sorry, it was a typo. And yes, it is in fact a bijection if you mean that the definition domain of $f$ is all $X$ and of $g$ is all $Y$.